# Move From XCode 7 and Swift 2.2 to XCode 8 Swift 2.3 : frame size changed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I have an UIImageView with 2 constraints for height and width (120 & 120)

Here's the class of my image:

```
class RoundImageView: UIImageView{
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Since the update the size of my frame is 1000 x 1000 and not 120 x 120...

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `layoutSubviews` instead of `awakeFromNib`